# How to update a field from a subquery with condition also the same from the same subquery?

Tags: postgresql-14

I need to update a table from a subquery with where condition the from the same subquery, in my case I want to update a field named "network", the network value is should I update is from the subquery named "sq"

```
UPDATE cdrs
   SET cdrs.network = sq.sysmap
   WHERE cdrs.iccid = sq.iccid (SELECT s.iccid, m.sysmap
                                  FROM sims s
                                  INNER JOIN mcc m
                                    ON s.session - >> 'mcc' = m.mcc
                                      AND s.session - >> 'mnc' = m.mnc) sq
     AND cdrs.network = '';
```

the condition of the cdrs.iccid also from the same subquery.

any idea?

Comment: Please post code so that it is formatted and clearly distinguishable from the narrative text. I've edited the post to format the query as well as possible given that it is not syntactically valid. It would also be helpful to provide the related tables' DDL along with example data and expected output so that there is sufficient context to help us help you. Please see [ask].